# Probability generating functions understanding

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, generating-functions

I have trouble understanding what exact relationship a probability generating function describes. On wikipedia it says that:

"In probability theory, the probability generating function of a discrete random variable is a power series representation (the generating function) of the probability mass function of the random variable"

but in the formulas i dont understand what the parameter z in G(z) represents or why we take the expected value of raising it to a random variable X like so: G(z) = E(z^X) = [Sum]

how does z depend on the distribution of X and how does one actually calculate probabilities of X taking a specific value once the PGF has been constructed with parameter z.

Im studying PGF:s in relation to stochastic processes and how they are used to express the rows of infinite transition matrices. I am so confused. Sorry I couldn't figure out how to represent the formula in latex here

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on MathJax notation](/help/notation), [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/259305) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).